# Graph API Explorer giving error on a simple get

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm a newbie at creating Facebook apps. I created a test application in Facebook and then brought up the Graph API explorer to test it (the drop down on the top right says my test application's name). After I get an access token (by pressing "Get Token"), I take the default query (`me?fields=id,name`) and press submit.

I then get the following error:

```
{   
  "error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "Gll8Nxv+a3E"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you request an User Access Token (by pressing "Get Access Token"), see

[image: screenshot]

You need to make sure that the Access Token field is filled by a long, cryptic string (not like in the screenshot).

Comment: Thanks for your response Tobi. Yes, I had got an access token as well before I hit submit. That is why I was wondering why it was saying I didn't have one.  I'm not able to put a screen shot in this comment box.